# Query about Oracle Connections

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I seem to be getting intermittent problems with my Oracle connection indicating something about a problem with semaphores which suggest that Oracle is somehow holding onto the connections instead of removing them after they have been used.

Here's the code and connection string I use:

Connection string: `user id=user;password=password;data source=dataSource; Validate Connection=true;Min Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=5;Connection Timeout=60;Incr Pool Size=5;`

And the code I use is this:

```
Dim OracleConn As New OracleConnection()
Dim DataTable As DataTable
Dim queryOracle As OracleCommand
Dim OracleDataAdapter As OracleDataAdapter
Dim connStr As String = "user id=user;password=password;data source=dataSource; Validate Connection=true;Min Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=5;Connection Timeout=60;Incr Pool Size=5;"
OracleConn.ConnectionString = connStr

Try

            OracleConn.Open()

            queryOracle = OracleConn.CreateCommand()

            queryOracle.CommandText = "select * from table1"

            DataTable = New DataTable()
            OracleDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(queryOracle)
            OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)

            table1.DataSource = DataTable.DefaultView
            table1.DataBind()

        Catch OracleEx As OracleException
            Throw
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally

            If Not OracleConn Is Nothing And OracleConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                OracleConn.Close()
            End If

        End Try
```

Now my questions are:

1. Is this the best way of doing this?
2. I only "Close" my connection do I need to "Dispose" of it also?

I'm using `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` by the way.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put everything between Using.

```
Using oracleConn as OracleConnection = new OracleConnection()
'Your stuff goes here
End Using
```

the same goes for Commands.

P.S. There's is no need to catch Exception if they are just thrown again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - by the way the only reason I throw at this stage is for testing purposes :)

Comment: Also should I put the using statement within a `Try Catch`?

Comment: Sorry another thing - if I use the `Using` method I have to reset the ConnectionString every time I use it - is that correct? Currently I set it once on `Page_Load` and use it throughout the page.

Comment: Please consult the MSDN Documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should not open any connection in a Page at all. That's the job ob the Business Layer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use using block (Execute Dispose in the end)

```
 Using connection As New OracleConnection()

   ....

 End Using
```

2 An application can call Close more than one time. No exception is generated.

If you called Dispose method SqlConnection object state will be reset. If you try to call any method on disposed SqlConnection object, you will receive exception.